# is it possible to use the messages from proto as dto, i.e. use the message type from protobuf schema file as it was a pojo class?

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, grpc

Context: I want to send to Kafka topic the request body sent to a Micronaut gRPC endpoint. The gRPC endpoint is an implementation of autogenerated Abstract Class from io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin

Current approach: In order to send to kafka topic a message receive from gRPC endpoint I am converting it to a DTO, property by property. I tried used the message from proto or some of the autogenerated properties from the object working as stubs but I didn't successed. Is my approach really a reasonable way to convert from message received to some object kafka can accept? It sounds to me I am duplicating effort and code.

The whole code can be found in [my git](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/account-control)

proto file with its message declaration (can I reuse them instead of duplicating in new kotlin class)

TransactionsService

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.mybank.endpoint";
option java_outer_classname = "TransactionsProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

package com.mybank.endpoint;

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service TransactionsService {
  rpc PostTransactions(TransactionsRequest) returns (TransactionsReply);
}

message TransactionsRequest {
  string transactionDesc = 1;
  repeated Transaction transactions = 2;
}
message Transaction {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
}

message TransactionsReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

autogenetarated stubs

```
package com.mybank.endpoint

import com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsServiceGrpc.getServiceDescriptor
import io.grpc.CallOptions
import io.grpc.CallOptions.DEFAULT
import io.grpc.Channel
import io.grpc.Metadata
import io.grpc.MethodDescriptor
import io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition
import io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition.builder
import io.grpc.ServiceDescriptor
import io.grpc.Status.UNIMPLEMENTED
import io.grpc.StatusException
import io.grpc.kotlin.AbstractCoroutineServerImpl
import io.grpc.kotlin.AbstractCoroutineStub
import io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls.unaryRpc
import io.grpc.kotlin.ServerCalls.unaryServerMethodDefinition
import io.grpc.kotlin.StubFor
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext
import kotlin.coroutines.EmptyCoroutineContext
import kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
import kotlin.jvm.JvmStatic

/**
 * Holder for Kotlin coroutine-based client and server APIs for
 * com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService.
 */
object TransactionsServiceGrpcKt {
  @JvmStatic
  val serviceDescriptor: ServiceDescriptor
    get() = TransactionsServiceGrpc.getServiceDescriptor()

  val postTransactionsMethod: MethodDescriptor<TransactionsRequest, TransactionsReply>
    @JvmStatic
    get() = TransactionsServiceGrpc.getPostTransactionsMethod()

  /**
   * A stub for issuing RPCs to a(n) com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService service as suspending
   * coroutines.
   */
  @StubFor(TransactionsServiceGrpc::class)
  class TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub @JvmOverloads constructor(
    channel: Channel,
    callOptions: CallOptions = DEFAULT
  ) : AbstractCoroutineStub<TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub>(channel, callOptions) {
    override fun build(channel: Channel, callOptions: CallOptions): TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub
        = TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub(channel, callOptions)

    /**
     * Executes this RPC and returns the response message, suspending until the RPC completes
     * with [`Status.OK`][io.grpc.Status].  If the RPC completes with another status, a
     * corresponding
     * [StatusException] is thrown.  If this coroutine is cancelled, the RPC is also cancelled
     * with the corresponding exception as a cause.
     *
     * @param request The request message to send to the server.
     *
     * @return The single response from the server.
     */
    suspend fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest): TransactionsReply = unaryRpc(
      channel,
      TransactionsServiceGrpc.getPostTransactionsMethod(),
      request,
      callOptions,
      Metadata()
    )}

  /**
   * Skeletal implementation of the com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService service based on Kotlin
   * coroutines.
   */
  abstract class TransactionsServiceCoroutineImplBase(
    coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
  ) : AbstractCoroutineServerImpl(coroutineContext) {
    /**
     * Returns the response to an RPC for com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService.PostTransactions.
     *
     * If this method fails with a [StatusException], the RPC will fail with the corresponding
     * [io.grpc.Status].  If this method fails with a [java.util.concurrent.CancellationException],
     * the RPC will fail
     * with status `Status.CANCELLED`.  If this method fails for any other reason, the RPC will
     * fail with `Status.UNKNOWN` with the exception as a cause.
     *
     * @param request The request from the client.
     */
    open suspend fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest): TransactionsReply = throw
        StatusException(UNIMPLEMENTED.withDescription("Method com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService.PostTransactions is unimplemented"))

    final override fun bindService(): ServerServiceDefinition = builder(getServiceDescriptor())
      .addMethod(unaryServerMethodDefinition(
      context = this.context,
      descriptor = TransactionsServiceGrpc.getPostTransactionsMethod(),
      implementation = ::postTransactions
    )).build()
  }
}
```

class implementing autogenerated stubs

```
package com.mybank.endpoint

import com.mybank.dto.Transactions
import com.mybank.dto.Transaction
import com.mybank.service.TransactionService
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class TransactionsEndpoint(val transactionService: TransactionService) : TransactionsServiceGrpcKt.TransactionsServiceCoroutineImplBase(){

    override suspend fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest): TransactionsReply {

        var dtoTransactions : Transactions = Transactions()
        var dtoTransaction : Transaction = Transaction()

        print(request.getTransactionDesc())
        print(request.getTransactionsList())
        print(request.getTransactions(0))


        dtoTransaction.id = request.getTransactions(0).id
        dtoTransaction.name = request.getTransactions(0).name
        dtoTransaction.description = request.getTransactions(0).description
        dtoTransactions.transactions  = listOf(dtoTransaction, dtoTransaction)
        dtoTransactions.transactionDesc = request.getTransactionDesc()

        transactionService.postDebitTransaction(dtoTransaction)

        transactionService.postDebitTransactions(dtoTransactions)
        return TransactionsReply.newBuilder().setMessage("testReply").build()
    }

}
```

DTOs that are nothing else than duplication of messages from proto

```
package com.mybank.dto

class Transaction {
    lateinit var id: String
    lateinit var name: String
    lateinit var description: String
}
```

and

```
package com.mybank.dto


class Transactions {
    lateinit var transactionDesc: String
    var transactions: List<Transaction>? = null
}
```

not relevant for this question but here is the producer working with DTOs

```
import com.mybank.dto.Transaction
import com.mybank.dto.Transactions
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaClient
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic

@KafkaClient
public interface DebitProducer {
    @Topic("debit")
    fun sendRequestMessage(@KafkaKey key: String?, message: String?) {
    }

    @Topic("debit")
    fun sendRequestMessage( transaction: Transaction) {
    }

    @Topic("debit")
    fun sendRequestMessage( transactions: Transactions) {
    }

    fun sendRequestMessage(@Topic topic: String?, @KafkaKey day: String?, message: String?) {}
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.3.72"
    id "application"
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13'
}

version "0.2"
group "account-control"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly
}

dependencies {
    kapt(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinxCoroutinesVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-server-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-client-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${grpcKotlinVersion}")

    //Kafka
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8")

    kaptTest("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")

    testImplementation enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.22.0")

    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0")
    testRuntime("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5")
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "account-control.Application"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

allOpen {
    annotation("io.micronaut.aop.Around")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        //Will retain parameter names for Java reflection
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}
//compileKotlin.dependsOn(generateProto)

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
    jvmArgs('-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protocVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${grpcKotlinVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have any idea? I am trying to generated POJO and convertors for reducing  code.